# Internet Explorer BHO, writing to registry and admin privileges

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, winapi, bho

for some reasons when I try to write to registry when IE doesn't run with admin privileges,

```
Utils::SetValueInRegistry(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,L"Software\\myApp23",L"Domain", value.c_str());
```

Anyone knows how to gain my BHO rights to write to registry everytime?
Or maybe should I write to another section to registry that's available for writing? The information I need to store is very dynamic and used in order to communicate between tabs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internet Explorer is running with Low Integrity Level. Use a key below `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\LowRegistry`

Comment: I tried your advice and somehow it works but I can't see no values added to these keys. where does it save it?

Comment: @user1326293: The whole point of "low integrity level" is to keep potentially damaging data isolated from other processes, possibly including your inspection tool.