# set registry setting using BHO in C#

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, 32bit-64bit, bho

I am trying to set a registry value using BHO.

it is working when i test a web application hosted in my machine, but when I check the created BHO is working with other websites, like Google.com, yahoo.com or any other website, it is not working.

I can read the registry value.
I have tried this method as well [`RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree`]. It is not working.

Is there any access rights I need to set? I could not found `LowRegistry` which is mentioned in  [given link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336437/internet-explorer-bho-writing-to-registry-and-admin-privileges?rq=1).

please help me on this.